# trying to get Statistics for data based on another parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

Struggling again on statistics on data based on other sets of data.

I have a list of customers. like the following:

```
CustomerID Value Date
1          3     01/01/2017
2          2     01/02/2017
3          1     01/02/2017
1          5     01/04/2017
1          6     01/04/2017
2          1     01/04/2017
2          2     01/04/2017
```

I want to get an average for a date range for Customer 1 on the days where customer 2 also has values. Does anyone have any thoughts?

example

```
 Select avg(value) 
 from Table where customerid=1 
 and (customer 2 values are not blank) 
 and date between '01/01/2017' and '01/31/2017'
```

I am using SQL Server Express 2012.

Comment: Do you want one average for all days or one average per day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another Option

```
Select AvgValue = Avg(Value+0.0)   -- Remove +0.0 if you want an INT
 From  YourTable 
 Where CustomerID = 1 
   and Date in (Select Distinct Date from YourTable Where CustomerID=2)
```

Returns

```
AvgValue
5.500000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the dates using `exists` or `in` and then calculate the average:

```
select avg(value)
from datatbl  t
where customerid = 1 and
      exists (select 1 from datatbl t2 where t2.customerId = 2 and t2.date = t.date);
```

If you want the average *per date*, then include `group by date`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'm sorry but the t and t2 are confusing me. If my table name is "Datatbl" would I write it like:
    select avg(value)
    from datatbl
    where customerid=1 and
          exists (select 1 from datatbl datatbl2 where datatbl2.customerID=2 
          and datatbl2.date=datatbl.date

I'm sorry I know this is a naive question...

Comment: Let me rephrase, if my table name is Datatbl, what should my query look like? I'm assuming the 't' and 't2' are referencing data I should know but I'm not getting it...